# Split an Image into different PictureBoxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I have a Image with size `187x16` which contain 10 smaller Images in a row.

I want split those Images into 10 different PictureBoxes.
Original Image:

[image: example image]

```
Dim fr_bm As New Bitmap(Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/images/u/image.gif"))
Dim to_bm As New Bitmap(16, 16)
Dim unitsimagearray(9) As Image
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(to_bm)
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    Dim fr_rect As New Rectangle(i * 19, 0, 16, 16) '0,19,38,76
    Dim to_rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16)
    gr.DrawImage(fr_bm, to_rect, fr_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    unitsimagearray(i) = to_bm
Next
u1.Image = unitsimagearray(0)
```

But the PictureBox shows all the splitted images.

Comment: That's ok but what is your question? what doesn't work. Samplecode

Comment: So, which is the width of each sub-image (the actual size of the grid)? Have you tried something to split them?

Comment: @nbk Question is clear , I want to split my image but i don't know how!

Comment: @Jimi 17x16 , i have googled it but I did not find the right answer

Comment: It looks like `17 * 10 <> 187`. Do you have a spare pixel? Where?

Comment: @Jimi there is a free space between each item i think

Comment: Well, you need to specify whether this pixel should be included in the final cut and where it is, in any case. Is it on the left or on the right? Also (and it's important) you need to show what you tried. There are plenty of examples around about selecting a section of an Image. In the MSDN Docs related to the Graphics object, too.

Comment: Look at this link. it explains how you create a new inage from the old, after calculating the size of the rectangle that you beed https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/374879-split-image-programmatically

Comment: @Jimi Check my codes , splitter is okay but picturebox shows all of splited images

Comment: @nbk Check my codes , splitter is okay but picturebox shows all of splited images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your current code is that the destination image (the image containing a *slice* of the original), is created once but painted many times.
Since the original image has transparent pixels, the result of the painting will be *accumulated*.
You can see the transparent sections overlapping.

It can be easily corrected, creating a new Bitmap for each slice of the original. You could also re-paint the same image with a transparent color, but this is faster.

In code, I'm assembling all the PictureBox controls that will receive the slices in one array, so you can assign the Image in the same loop that creates the Bitmaps.
You called the first PictureBox **`u1`**, so I'm following the same naming convention.

You will dispose of the Bitmap contained in the `unitsimagearray` when you don't need them anymore or the application closes.

---

**Original Bitmap (`.GIF`)**:

[image: Bitmap Grid]

Sliced images (2x). Anti-aliasing and transparency are preserved:

[image: Sliced Image]

```
Private unitsimagearray(9) As Bitmap

Dim imagePath As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "images/u/image.gif")
Dim picBoxes() As PictureBox = {u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10}

Using sourceBitmap As Bitmap = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath)))
    For idx As Integer = 0 To picBoxes.Length - 1
        Dim slice As Bitmap = New Bitmap(16, 16, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(slice)
            Dim sourceRect As New Rectangle(idx * 19, 0, 16, 16)
            Dim destinationRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16)
            g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, destinationRect, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            unitsimagearray(idx) = slice
            picBoxes(idx).Image = unitsimagearray(idx)
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```